# How to return array list which has specific char in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to return a list of names from an array list that doesn't have char 'a' as the last letter, I tried to make a loop for it and find the last letter from each name.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.addAll(Arrays.asList("Tomek", "Ania", "Krzys", "Tomek"));
   String last = names.get(names.size());
    int lastLetter = last.length() - 1;
    for (String word : names) {
        if (lastLetter != 'a' ) {
            System.out.println(names);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
["Tomek", "Krzys","Tomek"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
for (String word : names) {
    char lastLetter = word.toLowerCase().charAt(word.length() - 1);
    if (lastLetter != 'a') {
       toReturn.add(word);
    }
}
return toReturn;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8 or later you can use streams to filter the names as below.

```java
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Tomek", "Ania", "Krzys", "Tomek");
List<String> updated = names.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != 'a')
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
updated.forEach(System.out::println);
```

In the above code `names.stream()` convert the array to stream and `filter()` will filter the stream based on the preticate the last char of string is not `'a'` then the `collect` will create a new list with the filtered list.

Comment: Thank u so much, the first answer is for me more simple, for now i m begginer so maybe later i will use ur option.